# Are Enchantments affected by the type of armor?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

The type of armor (in this case, I don't mean the material, but whether it is a *helmet*, *chestplate*, *leggings*, or *boots*) helps determine the number of armor points that the equipped armor adds. Is the armor type also taken into account in determining how effective an enchantment is?

For example, say you have *Blast Protection IV* on a pair of *boots*; will that enchantment negate more damage from explosions if instead placed on a *chestplate*?

Comment: I don't *think* it does, completely not certain though.

Answer (score 1):

**No**. Every enchantment has the same effect regardless of the armor piece. Protection enchantments are added together and taken as an aggregate, not per armor piece.  Protection IV gives the same level of protection on boots as it does on a chestpiece. Therefore, it doesn't matter.

Answer (score -3):

protection IV protects th same on all armor pieces. There are some speciel enchantments wich can only be found on boots for example.

**enchantments**
*Boots:* Featherfalling
*Leggings:* non special
*Chestplate:* non special
*Helmet:* aqua affinity, respiration

[image]

taken from: [Minecraft Wiki enchanting](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Enchanting)

Edit: zoom in to see the picture :) (hold ctrl+scroll mousewheel

Comment: For the screen-shot, if you make the browser window smaller, the table will automatically narrow. I would recommend re-taking the screen-shot so you don't need to zoom in in order to read the text.